# edit, delete and drop down displaying correct field knockout js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

so I have a knockout js template which is displaying fields like this
[image], and can be edited, deleted and a new row can be added.
So when I click edit in instantor it shows "Choose company" instead of giving me first option as Instantor for editing.[image]
And lastly when I try to add a new item, it doesnt show choose company it just gives the option of instantor first instead of 'Choose company'shown like this.
[image]

So what I want to fix is, while editing it should show instantor instead of choose company and when I add new item it should show choose company instead of replicating the top field.

Here is the code for the templates.

```
 <script id="RRitemTmpl" type="text/html">
    <tr>           
        <td class="" data-bind="text: Company"></td>
        <td class="text-center" data-bind="text: third_party_rr_value"></td>
        <td class="text-center" style="vertical-align:middle;">
            <div data-bind="if: status() > 0">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-bind="click: $parent.editItem">Edit</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-bind="click: $parent.deleteItem">Delete</button>
            </div>
            <div data-bind="if: status() < 1">
                <span data-bind="text: status_description"></span>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</script>

<script id="RReditTmpl" type="text/html">
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center">
            <select id="selected_currency_local" class="form-control input-sm" data-bind="options: $root.availableCompanies,
                    optionsText: 'text_value',
                    value: $parent.selectedCompanyLocal,
                    optionsCaption: 'Choose Company'">
            </select>
        </td> 
        <td class="text-center">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm text-left" data-bind="value: third_party_rr_value" />
        </td>

        <td class="text-center" style="vertical-align:middle;">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-bind="click: $parent.acceptItemEdit">Accept</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-bind="click: $parent.cancelItemEdit">Cancel</button>
        </td>

    </tr>
</script>
```

Just incase if its necessary, I am giving the js file codes.

```
var ThirdPartyRRViewModel = function(parent, items) {

        var root = parent;
        var self = this;

        this.items = ko.observableArray(items);

        this.selectedItem = ko.observable();

        /*Observable for storing the data of the company selected */
        self.selectedCompanyLocal = ko.observable();

        this.addItem = function() {


             $.each(root.availableCompanies(), function (index, companyItem) {
                if (companyItem.ID == root.userRiskRate().Company) {
                    self.selectedCompanyLocal(companyItem);
                }
            });

            var newThird = {"ID":0, "ORIG_ID":0, "Company":self.selectedCompanyLocal().text_value, 
                            "third_party_rr_value":0, 
                            "status":1, "status_description":"Active"};

            var newItem = new ThirdPartyItem(newThird);
            self.items.push(newItem);
            self.selectedItem(newItem);
        };

        this.deleteItem = function(itemToDelete) {
            /* If ORIG_ID is greater than > 0, useropenloan row has been read from the database 
               and can not be removed, but cancelled. */
            if (itemToDelete.ORIG_ID() > 0) {
                itemToDelete.status(-1); /* Indicates to server that this item should be updated to cancelled. */ 
                itemToDelete.status_description('Will be cancelled');
                itemToDelete.itemIsEdited(1);
            } else {
                 self.items.remove(itemToDelete);
            }
            self.selectedItem(null);
        };

        this.editItem = function(ThirdPartyItem) {
            $.each(root.availableCompanies(), function (index, companyItem) {
                if (companyItem.ID == ThirdPartyItem.Company()) {
                    self.selectedCompanyLocal(companyItem);
                }
            });
            self.selectedItem(ThirdPartyItem);
        };

        this.acceptItemEdit = function() {
            self.selectedItem().third_party_rr_type(self.selectedCompanyLocal().text_code);  
            self.selectedItem().Company(self.selectedCompanyLocal().text_value);  
            self.selectedItem().third_party_rr_type.commit();
            self.selectedItem().Company.commit();
            self.selectedItem().third_party_rr_value.commit();
            self.selectedItem().itemIsEdited(1);
            self.selectedItem(null);
            self.selectedCompanyLocal(null);
        };

        this.cancelItemEdit = function() {
            self.selectedItem().Company.reset();
            self.selectedItem().third_party_rr_value.reset();
            self.selectedItem(null);
            self.selectedCompanyLocal(null);
        };

        this.templateToUse = function(item) {
            return self.selectedItem() === item ? "RReditTmpl" : "RRitemTmpl";
        };
    };
```

Comment: I'm assuming that the data binding is wrong.  What happens if you change: value: $parent.selectedCompanyLocal to value: $data.selectedCompanyLocal ?

Comment: @Kris When I changed it to what you said, now the new Item when it gets added it says Company ! :D Thanks one problem got fixed, now only the problem is when you click edit it shows Choose company instead of instantor

Comment: Can you confirm that the selected item when you Add is the same when you Edit?

Comment: @Kris okay when I change it to data, it doesnt save the other options, it only saves instantor, so I guess its wrong..

Comment: @Kris yea when its $parent, then what I add is what I will edit, but when I add instantor I can edit it to anything else, there is some more options but It doesnt show Choose company..

Comment: Hrmm, I see. Try: value: $parent.selectedCompanyLocal()

Comment: Doesnt work, I think my this.addItem is wrong... @Kris

Comment: @Kris I fixed the edit codes, so right now only NEW ITEM doesnt show Choose company

Comment: If you want it to show Choose company, i would assume that by default no company should be set. i.e. null.

Comment: @Kris so where do I make it null ? I was thinkin in var newThird the company should be changed?

Comment: @Kris I found my mistakes!!!! Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code change `"Company":self.selectedCompanyLocal().text_value`, to `"Company":self.selectedCompanyLocal()`
It should work.

Comment: Yea Thanks! Thats the way to do it, I figured it out later.